# Why i am getting invalid date and NaN here?

Tags: javascript

```
var now = new Date;
var timenow = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()].join(':');
var date1 = '2011/11/30';
var dat = new Date(date1 +timenow);
document.write(dat);
document.write(Date.parse(dat));
```

I am getting the date string from my service and then appending the time, why it is throwing me invalid date.

Comment: Sometimes I'm shocked at how little debugging people do on their own sometimes.

Comment: @32bitkid Why? Stackoverflow community can debug the code for you, see for yourself.

Comment: You could also use the date constructor; `new Date(2011, 11 - 1, 30, now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds());`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing a space after the date, so you're trying to parse something like `2011/11/3013:44:02` rather than `2011/11/30 13:44:02`.

```
var now = new Date;
var timenow = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()].join(':');
var date1 = '2011/11/30 ';
var dat = new Date(date1 + timenow);
document.write(dat);
document.write(Date.parse(dat));
```

Comment: Also I'm not sure how nice Date.parse plays with single digit seconds and minutes. It would probably be better to just set the month, day, year on `now`, rather than relying on `parse`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var now = new Date;
var timenow = [now.getHours(),now.getMinutes(),now.getSeconds()].join(':');
var date1 = '2011/11/30';
var dat = Date(date1 + timenow);
document.write(dat);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dUSHu/4/) is the working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Because he cant parse correctly. Look this example: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AHp6Y/1/)

new Date => () missing.

on var dat is empty space missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `date1 + timenow` string, which you are feeding into the `Date` constructor, would look something like this:

```
2011/11/3014:34:53
```

This is not a valid date specification as per the [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) method (using the `Date` constructor like this is equivalent to calling `parse`), so you get an invalid result. Do this instead:

```
var dat = new Date(date1.replace(/\//g, '-') + "T" + timenow);
```

This makes your string look like `2011-11-30T14:34:53`, which is a format supported by `parse`.